# Disable NetworkAdapter CMD

Tags: powershell, cmd

How can I run this powershell script in cmd?

```
$adaptor = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*Wireless*"}
$adaptor.Disable()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure CMD is elevated. You could use WMIC directly from CMD:

```
wmic nic where "NetConnectionID like '%wireless%'" call disable
```

Comment: If I look at the code it looks good, but It Says No Instance(s) Available, what's wrong?? Thx for your answer :)

Comment: Start by getting the names of your adapters: wmic path win32_networkadapter get netconnectionid. Do you get names with 'wireless' in it?

Answer (score 1):

you can pass commands to the powershell executeable via the `-Command` switch and prefixing the script block with `&`.

```
powershell -Command "& { $adaptor = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*Wireless*"}; $adaptor.Disable() }"
```

You can read more by running the command `powershell -?`

Comment: Thx Scott Chamberlain :)